# Why aren't there any hero affinities in Dota2?

Tags: dota-2

In the attempt to elaborate this question:

1. Why aren't poison-based heroes (e.g. Viper, Venomancer, Shadow Demon) immune from poison?
2. Why does Zeus get equally damaged by lightning blasts from Maelstrom?
3. Why isn't Doom's fiery Scorched Earth quickly melting Crystal Maiden's Frostbite?

And lot's more, in the direction of:

1. Don't you think it'll elevate the gameplay in terms of drafting?
2. Other than just timings, don't you think affinities will provide more depth in the way spell combinations are being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinities would change the gameplay **dramatically**. Every hero, every item and every strategy would be totally different from what they used to be.

The changes in MOBAs are created gradually. For instance, a new item, a new hero, the remake of a spell etc. This is to make the game coherent. Remember, Dota 2 is an e-sport with millions of dollars in terms of prizes every year. A dramatic change like that would turn everything upside down. When your product produces money you don't change the recipe. It's like suddenly changing the very core rules of Basketball. You can't. Not when you have millions of players and hundreds of millions in revenue.

A dramatic change like that sounds like Dota 3 to me or even a whole different game.

---

To answer your other questions:

> Don't you think it'll elevate the gameplay in terms of drafting? Other than just timings, don't you think affinities will provide more depth in the way spell combinations are being executed?

This is a personal opinion but **YES**, something like that sounds awesome. Nevertheless I wouldn't expect a dramatic change like that for the reasons stated above.